# Postar em uma fan page utilizando WebBrowser

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

Estou fazendo uma aplicação para postar nas minhas fan pages, já faço login, listo as fan pages, está tudo certo.

Só não estou conseguindo colocar o texto na caixa de texto do facebook.

Olhem aqui:

```
<div data-block="true" data-offset-key="72l55-0-0" class="_209g _2vxa">
<span data-offset-key="72l55-0-0">
    <span data-text="true">Preciso colocar o texto aqui!!!</span>
</span>
```

```
HtmlElementCollection items = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
{
    if (item.GetAttribute("classname") == "_209g _2vxa")
    {
        item.InnerText = "oiii " + DateTime.Now;
        item.InvokeMember("click");
        //SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
    }
}
```

Comment: É uma pergunta boba, mas não seria melhor usar a API do Facebook?

Comment: Randrade, problema que a API não me deixa publicar em Grupos Fechados, somente Grupos Públicos.

Comment: Nesse caso, você está querendo fazer algo que não é permitido pelo Facebook. Vale ressaltar que isso pode causar banimento da conta em que estará realizando as inserções.

Comment: É permitido sim desde que use o browser! Onde isso é proibido?

Comment: Se é permitido, tem na API, por exemplo, o aplicativo de Facebook para Android posta normalmente em grupos fechados, portanto ele usa a API do Facebook.